# Cómo filtrar por un buscador una nota, independientemente de si el usuario escribe en mayúscula o minúscula

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState('');
const addNote = (inputText, text) => {
    const date = new Date();
    const newNote = {
      id: nanoid(),
      title: inputText,
      text: text,
      date: date.toLocaleString()
      
    }
    const newNotes = [newNote, ...notes];
    setNotes(newNotes)
  }

const filterNotes = notes.filter((noteText) => noteText.title.toUpperCase().includes(searchText));
```

Se encarga de tomar de un array de objetos, la clave title, convertirlo todo a mayúsculas, y compararlo con la variable `seachText` la cual es un string.

Esto hace que en mi buscador de mi todolist hecho en react.js si ponemos cualquier texto (en mayúscula) va a filtrar y comparar, si hay alguna nota que incluya el texto del buscador, lo va a mostrar.

El problema que se me presenta es que si el usuario escribe en el buscador en minúscula, no muestra nada (obviamente, ya que recibe la cadena en mayúsculas), y lo que busco es que **independientemente** de lo que el usuario escriba, (mayus o minus), filtre la cadena que se le pasa y si coincide que la muestre.

¿Cómo podría plantear esto?

Answer (score 1):

Sin pensar en que usas react y haya algo ya listo, se me ocurre que puedes transformar todo, siempre, a una de las dos cosas y comparar todo en un lugar común

```js
let string1 = "pepe";
let string2 = "PEPE";
let areEqual = string1.toUpperCase() === string2.toUpperCase();
console.log(areEqual);
```

También puedes usar [string::localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```js
let areEqual = 'xyz'.localeCompare('XyZ', undefined, { sensitivity: 'base' }); // retorna 0
console.log(areEqual);
```

Comment: Al final el problema se ha solucionado fácil porque olvidé añadir un .toLowerCase() a la variable searchText, entonces hace siempre correctamente la comparación, muchas gracias por el comentario igualmente ^^